# Get resistor values for voltage divider/attenuator

Tags: audio, level

I have a 10 V audio source that I want to bring to line level: 1 V. That's pretty easy: I just need to use a voltage attenuator, 10:1, like in the image below. I used resistor values of 1 k\$\Omega\$ (\$R_1\$) and 100 \$\Omega\$ (\$R_2\$) and it worked great, but I have a question: what if I had used 100 k\$\Omega\$ and 10 k\$\Omega\$ resistors? The ratio is still 10:1, but I think it would not produce a good result (I have no idea why I think so).

Would you please tell me if I am right? If so, should I use 100 \$\Omega\$ (\$R_1\$) and 10 \$\Omega\$ (\$R_2\$) resistors instead of 1 k\$\Omega\$ and 100 \$\Omega\$ I am currently using? Would it be a good idea? I just want to bring this 10 V speaker level to line level and so far using 1 k\$\Omega\$/100 \$\Omega\$ worked fine (no noise, no humming)... but I am wondering if I am doing it right. Should I try different resistor values (while keeping the same ratio, of course)?

[image]

Comment: It depends on the out- and input impedances of the source and destination device. Too low values will overload the source. Too high values will attenuate the signal more then wanted as the destination impedance starts to skew the divider ratio.

Comment: To get 10 to 1 you would want 9k and 1k. The output voltage Vout = Vs * R2 / (R1 + Rs).  Or, what I mean is, the ration is 9 to 1, not 10 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you should continue using low resistances, since you insinuated that the source of the signal is a power amplifier driving a loudspeaker. If so, it should easily be able to drive an extra 100Ω load.

Also, without knowing the input impedance of the next stage, lower is better.

I should also point out that you are dividing by 11, not 10. To divide by ten, you need resistors in the ratio 9:1, not 10:1.

To be extra sure we also need to consider the power being dissipated in the resistors, using a variant of the power law, \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$. We know the voltage across the 100Ω resistor will be about 10V, and the voltage across the 10Ω resistor will be approximately 1V:

$$ P_{100} = \frac{10^2}{100} = 1W $$

and:

$$ P_{10} = \frac{1^2}{10} = 0.1W $$

That 100Ω resistor is likely to get hot, so make sure it's *at least* a 1W rated device, preferably 2W.

If you only have quarter-watt resistors available, we can work out what resistance value will *just* tolerate 10V across it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R &= \frac{V^2}{P} \\ \\
&= \frac{10^2}{0.25} \\ \\
&= 400\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

Bump that up to 470Ω, to be safe, and for convenience. You can use 0.25W resistors of values 470Ω and 47Ω, and they won't overheat.

Comment: You answer is very clear! I took a look at the specification of line output, and it says it should produce a load between 100 and 600 ohm. In my case, if I use a potentiometer of 1k with a 100ohm (R2), what would be the resulting load when the potentiometer is at 1k ohm and when the potentiometer is at 0 ohm? I think the load value will be exactly the potentiometer value, right? So I should add a 100ohm resistor in series with it to make sure I never get below 100 ohm?

Comment: @user314164 I didn't really understand what you're getting at. I think if you plan to use a pot, you should raise a new question, because that's getting away from the original question.